# pulling a list based on the key

Tags: groovy

I have a record as

```
["name1":["value1":10, "value2":name1, "value3":150, "value4":20],
 "name2":["value1":10, "value2":name2, "value3":150, "value4":20]]
```

I have a list where the values are `name1, name2`, etc.

I want to pull the list depending on the name1 as

```
["name1":["value1":10, "value2":name1, "value3":150, "value4":20]]
```

.subMap(["name1"]) did work for me, but I have a list and by looping the list I need to pull the values

```
Ex : namesList.each{record ->
          newMap = firstmap.subMap(record)
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **subMap(Collection keys)**:

```
def map = ["name1":["value1":10, "value2":"name1", "value3":150, "value4":20],
           "name2":["value1":10, "value2":"name2", "value3":150, "value4":20]]

//Answer here, return Map still:
println map.subMap("name1")
//Or
println map.subMap(["name1", "name2"])
```

Comment: the edited option did work for me...let me test further...Thank you very much

Comment: Hi, if I need to pull this by using a loop of a list, how do I do that ? for each string of a list I need to perform this operation, but not successful in pulling the list by using any of the tariffRecMap.subMap([offer]), etc(edited my question)